# VLC show file in folder

Tags: vlc-media-player

I sometimes browse my `short-length` videos collection. Then I i.e. find some funny one and I want to copy it somewhere else or send it to a friend. The problem is, that the collection is really big, so I don't want to scroll it just looking on thumbnails.

The best option would be to open this file in a folder, so I would get `explorer.exe` with collection directory and the current video selected. But I cannot quite find that option in VLC. Do you guys know if there's one like this? Or maybe in a form of `lua` extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click the video and choose information, then copy the path to the file, then press `win+r` and enter `explorer.exe /select,c:\path\to\file.wmv`

### Edit:

I made a primitive lua extension that uses this command. Tested with vlc 3.0.4 on windows 10 x64.

#### usage:

- Save the script in the extensions folder.
- Play the desired video to
  make it the current playlist item(just selecting in the playlist is
  not enough.)
- Open the extension `view->select_in_explorer`
- Click the
  button "select in explorer" in the dialog window.
- The explorer should
  open with the file selected.

#### select_in_explorer.lua

```
-- "select_in_explorer.lua" -- VLC Extension

function descriptor()
    return {
        title = "Select in explorer",
        version = "0.1",
        author = "mb",
        url = "",
        shortdesc = "Select in explorer",
        description = [[opens Windows explorer and select the currently played file]],
        capabilities = {}
    }
end

function activate()
    dlg = vlc.dialog("Select in explorer")
    update_dialog()
end

function deactivate()
end

function close()
        vlc.deactivate()
end

function meta_changed()
    return false
end

function update_dialog()
    path = vlc.playlist.get(vlc.playlist.current()).path
    dlg:add_button("select in explorer",select_in_explorer, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    path_label = dlg:add_label(path, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    dlg:show()
end

function select_in_explorer()
    path = vlc.playlist.get(vlc.playlist.current()).path
    cmd = "explorer.exe /select,"..path
    io.popen(cmd)
end
```

Comment: Thank you man! That really solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of completeness...

- on macOS you can right click > Reveal in Finder - which will highlight the file directly.
- on Windows, right click > Show containing folder [though in a large folder, that's going to be less useful]